# Can a cookie be made in HTTPS, and used in HTTP if secure is false?

Tags: php, cookies, ssl, https

Can a cookie be made in `HTTPS`, and used in `HTTP` if secure parameter of the cookie is set false? I have a website where I only require a single page to be in `HTTPS`, such as the login or maybe a special feature page.

I assume that the cookie will be (safe as it is transfered with SSL) although sent back as non-hashed when on a non-SSL page, is safe to assume so?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You might find [`$cookie->setSecureOnly($secureOnly)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L141) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: yes.

Setting a cookie on an SSL secured response, but leaving out the `secure` flag, will make the cookie behave no different than if it was transferred over a non-SSL connection.

Answer (score 4):

A cookie can be used on either HTTP or HTTPS unless it's marked a secure.  If marked as secure the browser will only send it if the current request is on HTTPS.

If your current request is HTTP then cookie will be sent "in-the-clear" and may be able to be intercepted by a man-in-the-middle or by someone sniffing traffic.  Google "firesheep" for an example of why this can be bad.